# Python: Speeding up script with inputs of > billion rows

Tags: python, performance, python-2.7

I've seen a lot of tips going around on how to speed up python code or make it more efficient. I've tried some things on the code below like: change global variables to local variables, whenever possible, using .format to create strings instead of adding strings, trying to not create multiple variables. But still, this script takes 1h25 to run. I have two input files:

1) A bed file, two column (tab delimited) file with number or code in the first column, and numbers in the second column. It has ~2 billion lines, where the combination of numbers is unique (it has all the positions in a genome; the first column is the chromosome, the second is the position):

> 1 1
>
> 1 2
>
> 1 3
>
> 1 4
>
> ...

2) a complex file, where the first few (~3000 lines) are a header that start with #, and then an entry for, again, a combination of number/code + number in the first two columns. This two columns make the link with the first file (1 1 in file 1 is the the same as 1 1 in file 2). This has ~22 million of rows. Here is an example of the first three lines:

```
1   1   .   G   .   32.9939 .   DP=1;MQ0F=0;AF1=0;AC1=0;DP4=1,0,0,0;MQ=60;FQ=-29.9923   GT:PL:GQ    0/1:0:36
1   2   .   T   .   32.9939 .   DP=1;MQ0F=0;AF1=0;AC1=0;DP4=1,0,0,0;MQ=60;FQ=-29.9923   GT:PL:GQ    ./.:0:36
1   3   .   C   .   32.9939 .   DP=1;MQ0F=0;AF1=0;AC1=0;DP4=1,0,0,0;MQ=60;FQ=-29.9923   GT:PL:GQ    1/1:0:36
```

Question: I want to filter rows in the first file, if those rows on the second file have a 0/0, 0/1 or 1/1 (the 4th possibility is ./.) in the last column (so I need to pars the last column, to reach those three characters)

The added complexity is that file #2 has to be read through a pipe from another program because it's compressed in a specific way done by that program (opening this file takes a long time on its own but nothing I can do about it...)

Call: program view file2.vcf.gz | my_script.py file1.bed

```
import sys
import re
import time

start_time = time.time()


def make_vcf_dict(vcf):
    mydict={}
    for line in (line for line in vcf if not line.startswith("#")):
            line=line.strip().split()
            genotype=line[-1].split(':')[0]

            motif=re.compile('\./\.')
            if motif.match(genotype) is None:
                mydict.setdefault('{}:{}'.format(line[0],line[1]),'{}:{}'.format(line[0],line[1]))

    return mydict

def create_output_bed(bed,data):

    print "creating output"
    for line in (line for line in data if line.startswith('#CHROM')):
        output_name='{}_mask_positions.bed'.format(line.strip().split()[-1])
    print output_name
    output=open(output_name,'w') 

    print "making dictionary"   
    for line in bed:
        line=line.strip().split()
    #creating the same entry as in dict:
        region='{}:{}'.format(line[0], line[1])
        if region not in mydict:
            output.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line[0],line[1]))
    output.close()
    bed.close()
    return

print "reading data"
data=sys.stdin.readlines()  #.readlines here is key!!

mydict=make_vcf_dict(data)

#read the bed file:
print "Writing output"
create_output_bed(open(sys.argv[1],'r'),data)

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I was wondering if there would be a more efficient way to deal with this entirely? Not making a dictionary, splitting my file? I have a 32 core server to deal with this and little experience with scripting...
Thank you!

Comment: This may be a stupid question, but why do you need the first file at all? Couldn't you just collect all the chromosome/position info from the second file (where the lines contain `1/0` etc.) into a set, turn that into a list, sort that and be done with it?

Comment: The reason is because I need all the positions that are NOT in the second file with a 0/0, 1/1 and 0/1. This includes in the second file that are ./. AND others that are not in that file at all because they were filtered along the way. The second file does not contain all the positions in the first bed file, just a subset... That's my problem... That's why I was going through every position in the first file, asking if it is in the second with a ./. and if not, exclude that from the bed file.

Comment: Is it important to keep the original order of the files?

Comment: @LiranFunaro, No, it is not.

Comment: Could you check for us how much of that time is due to the unzip? Just unzip the file without the script and check how long did it take.

Comment: I suggest you to convert the 2nd file to a format which can be read by [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) and then use pandas for the checks with the first file. You could read in the content of the first file in batches and then check those batches against the 2nd file. Also at [codereview.stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) you usually get good suggestions when it comes to performance improvements of your code.

Comment: @LiranFunaro Unzipping takes about 10 min

Comment: @MattS I just read that you're on a multicore server so you might also want to take a look at [multi threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). You could have one thread which populates a [Queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/queue.html) with contents from the first file and multiple threads which all read from the queue and identify the matches (possibly pushing them to a second queue from which another thread reads and which can save those matches to a file for example).

Comment: If you're then bottlenecking at populating the queue you could also chunk the first file and have multiple threads populating the queue (take a look at [memory maps](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mmap.html)). However you probably soon hit the point where the I/O speed is the limiting part but that depends a lot on the storage medium you're using.

Answer (score 1):

If the second file has only a few million rows (not billion as the first), then I expect the data to fit in the memory.

> I have a 32 core server to deal with this

Parallelizing it won't help you much because the main bottleneck is the disk, not the CPU. Unless the data was distributed among many files on different disks.

However, you do have some improvements you can make:

- Move the regex compilation outside the loop (`motif=re.compile('\./\.')`).
- Use `set` instead of `dict`.
- Avoid the `format`, just use a `tuple`.
- Don't read all the lines beforehand.
- Avoid going over stdin twice.
- Avoid doing anything twice.

```py
import sys
import re
import time

start_time = time.time()

def make_vcf(vcf_input):
    output = set()
    motif=re.compile('\./\.')

    for line in vcf_input:
        line = line.strip().split()
        if line[0].startswith('#CHROM'):
            output_name = '{}_mask_positions.bed'.format(line[-1])
            continue
        elif line[0].startswith("#"):
            continue

        genotype=line[-1].split(':')[0]

        if motif.match(genotype) is None:
            output.add( (line[0],line[1]) )

    return output_name, output


def create_output_bed(output_name, vcf, bed):
    print "creating output:", output_name
    output = open(output_name,'w') 

    print "making dictionary"   
    for line in bed:
        line = line.strip().split()
        #creating the same entry as in dict:
        region = line[0], line[1]
        if region not in vcf:
            output.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(line[0],line[1]))
    output.close()
    bed.close()
    return

print "reading data"  
output_name, vcf = make_vcf(sys.stdin.readlines())

#read the bed file:
print "Writing output"
create_output_bed(output_name, vcf, open(sys.argv[1],'r'))

print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: It would be nice to know the reason for the downvote, so I could improve my answer.

Comment: I didn't down grade you :/ I'm going to give this a try. Can I ask why is set faster than dictionaries? Thank you! I'm also checking the unzip time.

Comment: It is just stored less data which might help the locality of the cache. I don't know the exact implementation, but both implementations might actually be very similar.

Comment: I think it saves around 20% of the time (I tried with a much smaller subset of these files though). I'll try with a bigger one. Thank you!

Comment: if I don't use sys.stdin.readlines() it throughs me this error: TypeError: 'file' object is not callable; with it, it works correctly.